# how to change default parameter of commands that generate automatically in Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

Suppose there are only 3 files: a.h a.cpp main.cpp in the project. I am using ubuntu 14.04

Makefile:

```
CFLAG=-Wall
CC=clang

m:main.o a.o
  ${CC} ${CFLAG} -o $@ $^

a.o:a.h   
main.o:a.h
```

The problem is when compiling a.o,it will generate command like this:

```
g++ -c -o a.o a.cpp
```

but what I expected is:

```
clang -Wall -c -o a.o a.cpp
```

Are there any other ideas except for rewriting Makefile like this:

```
a.o:a.cpp a.h
   ${CC} ${CFLAG} -o $@ a.cpp
main.o:a.h main.cpp
   ${CC} ${CFLAG} -o $@ main.cpp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the [GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html), the variable that by convention holds the C++ compiler is `CXX` not `CC`. `CC` is for the C complier.

So adding the line:

```
CXX=clang
```

should solve your problem.

I would then refactor your use of `CC` to `CXX` in order to be consistent and conventional.

With the Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS=-Wall
CXX=clang

m:main.o a.o
        ${CXX} ${CXXSFLAGS} -o $@ $^

a.o:a.h
main.o:a.h
```

Calling make gives me:

```
$ make
clang -Wall   -c -o main.o main.cpp
clang -Wall   -c -o a.o a.cpp
clang  -o m main.o a.o
```

Comment: it works now after I change CFLAGS to CXXFLAGS, Thanks!